# Tensorflow matmul dimensions error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am running the following code and the final line throws an error.

```
weights = tf.Variable(
tf.truncated_normal([DATA_POINTS, hidden1_units],
                        stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(DATA_POINTS))),
    name='weights')
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden1_units]),
                     name='biases')
hidden1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(images, weights) + biases)
```

Error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [96,336], In[1]: [366,128]
```

I'm confused on why am I getting this error. Shouldn't multiplying a [96,366] matrix by a [366,128] matrix work?

Thanks

Comment: it's 336, not 366, note the middle number

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It was a typo in my code (said 366 instead of 336).